# XmlSerializer flatten a List

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have an unfortunate problem with the default implementation of a Class.
The structure I'm trying to serialize looks somewhat like this:

```
public class Request
{
    public Point[] Points { get; set; }
}
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the service I'm trying to send this file to requires a structure like this

```
<Request>
    <X1>1.0</X1>
    <Y1>1.0</Y1>
    ...
    <Xn>2.0</Xn>
    <Yn>2.0</Yn>
</Request>
```

While I'm aware that i can flatten the array to serialize its properties as attributes I can't find a way to match the required format I have here.

Is there any way I can achieve this with the default XmlSerializer?

It seems like I would have to implement IXmlSerializable manually. If so, is there any way I can just customize the behaviour for this specific List without having to implement the whole serialization and deserialization manually?

Answer (score 0):

Once you serialize the Request class, you may then use an XSLT transformation as an intermediate step to gain what you are trying to do.

Lets assume that the initial XML is as shown below

```
    <Request>
    <Points>
    <Point>
    <X>5</X>
    <Y>6</Y>
    </Point>
    <Point>
    <X>7</X>
    <Y>8</Y>
    </Point>
    <Point>
    <X>9</X>
    <Y>10</Y>
    </Point>
    </Points>
    </Request>
```

The below code shows how that can be accomplished.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Xml.Xsl;

    namespace StackOverflow
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string xslMarkup = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
        <xsl:template match='/'>
    <Request>

       <xsl:for-each select='Request/Points/Point'>

         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;X</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select='position()'/>
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select='X'/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;/X</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select='position()'/>
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&gt;</xsl:text>

      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;Y</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select='position()'/>
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select='Y'/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;/Y</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select='position()'/>
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&gt;</xsl:text>


       </xsl:for-each>

    </Request>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>";

                XDocument xmlTree = new XDocument(
                    new XElement("Request",
                        new XElement("Points",
                            new XElement("Point",
                                new XElement("X", "5"),
                                new XElement("Y", "6")
                                ),
                                 new XElement("Point",
                                    new XElement("X", "7"),
                                    new XElement("Y", "8")
                                    ),
                                     new XElement("Point",
                                        new XElement("X", "9"),
                                        new XElement("Y", "10")
                                        )

                    )
                    )
                );

                XDocument newTree = new XDocument();
                using (XmlWriter writer = newTree.CreateWriter())
                {
                    // Load the style sheet.
                    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslMarkup)));

                    // Execute the transform and output the results to a writer.
                    xslt.Transform(xmlTree.CreateReader(), writer);
                }



                Console.WriteLine(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(newTree.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

The output obtained is as shown below

```
<Request><X1>5</X1><Y1>6</Y1><X2>7</X2><Y2>8</Y2><X3>9</X3><Y3>10</Y3></Request>
```